# Does not calling org.apache.ignite.transactions.Transaction#close after a #commit or #rollback cause leaks/problems?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I recently noticed while debugging some issues that a poorly written piece of code DOES NOT call `org.apache.ignite.transactions.Transaction#close` after calling `org.apache.ignite.transactions.Transaction#rollback`. It was neither using try-with-resources nor doing it in a finally.

I am aware and see it mentioned in the [docs](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.5/docs/transactions#Transaction%20Object%20Lifecycle) as-well that Ignite Transaction object needs to be closed after use.

My question is what is the impact of this. Would it result in leaks or other issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From glancing in the code, it should not be a problem. `close()` waits on a future (which should already happen when doing `rollback()`) and then returns if transaction is `COMMITTED` or `ROLLED_BACK`. Not missing anything important.

Comment: Cool...so is it safe to say this would not cause any problems?

Comment: Should be OK, I still recommend to fix eventually.